# Override the moment js default invalid date text

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How can I override the moment.js

```
var defaultInvalidDate = 'Invalid date';
```

without changing the moment.js file. Just like my site overrides certain bootstrap css styles with a Site.css, so when bootstrap is updated I dont lose the changes, is there any way to make overrides for momentjs?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just update your current locale used by `moment.js` using `moment.updateLocale(localeName, config)`

```
moment.updateLocale(moment.locale(), { invalidDate: "Invalid Date Updated" })
```

Here is the working example:

```js
console.log(moment(new Date("Aa")).format(""));
moment.updateLocale(moment.locale(), { invalidDate: "Invalid Date Updated" })
console.log(moment(new Date("Aa")).format(""));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also edit the locale file in moment package directly.

For an example to change invalid date message for DE, find the locale file which is *moment/locale/de.js* and then add following under *moment.defineLocale*:

```
invalidDate: function() {
  return 'Date Invalid';
}
```

JS Fiddle https://fiddle.jshell.net/dzcz07um/